# ImportError: cannot import name DefaultEngineStrategy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run a python game source I made, but everytime I do "python Login.py" I get this whole traceback:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Login.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Houdini.HoudiniFactory import HoudiniFactory
  File "/var/xsource/Houdini/HoudiniFactory.py", line 18, in <module>
    from Houdini.Crumbs import retrieveItemCollection, retrieveRoomCollection, \
  File "/var/xsource/Houdini/Crumbs/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from Houdini.Crumbs.Room import RoomSchema, RoomCollection
  File "/var/xsource/Houdini/Crumbs/Room.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Houdini.Handlers.Games.Table import leaveTable
  File "/var/xsource/Houdini/Handlers/Games/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Houdini.Handlers.Play.Moderation import cheatBan
  File "/var/xsource/Houdini/Handlers/Play/Moderation.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Houdini.Data.Penguin import Penguin
  File "/var/xsource/Houdini/Data/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from alchimia.engine import TwistedEngine
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alchimia/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from alchimia.strategy import TWISTED_STRATEGY
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alchimia/strategy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.engine.strategies import DefaultEngineStrategy
ImportError: cannot import name DefaultEngineStrategy
```

If someone knows how to fix this please let me know, thank you so much!

Comment: `DefaultEngineStrategy` and the other contents of `sqlalchemy.engine.strategies` seem to have been removed in SQLAlchemy v. 1.4. Try installing a previous version and see if that works.

Comment: You should post code snippet from Login.py so people can help you better